# How to build F# application with command line

Tags: f#

My F# project consists of three files, and has dependencies to two 3rd party DLLs. Currently, I use a VS2019 project with NuGet package dependencies, and I am able to build and run the project using VS2019 commands. I am also able to build and run my app using command line and `dotnet run MyProject.fsproj` command. Currently it's a dotnet core 3.1 project, but it does not necessarily have to be such: the most important part for me is to be able to have three source files: two with my implementation, and one with `main` entry point.

My problem is, I need to build and run the project in a setup I cannot control, with a severely constrained quota of execution time of a couple of seconds (approximately 10s). I am trying to squeeze out every easily accessible second and I wonder if it would be possible to compile and build the project without an overhead of complex build process of `dotnet build` and MSBuild, invoking `fsc.exe` directly. However, I cannot even tests the idea because I am not able to get a runnable executable right.

Looking at the logs of VS, I found it uses following command to run `fsc.exe`:

```
"c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\fsharp\Tools\fsc.exe" -o:obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProject.dll ^
-g ^
--debug:portable ^
--noframework ^
--define:TRACE ^
--define:DEBUG ^
--define:NETCOREAPP ^
--define:NETCOREAPP3_1 ^
--define:NETCOREAPP1_0_OR_GREATER ^
--define:NETCOREAPP1_1_OR_GREATER ^
--define:NETCOREAPP2_0_OR_GREATER ^
--define:NETCOREAPP2_1_OR_GREATER ^
--define:NETCOREAPP2_2_OR_GREATER ^
--define:NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER ^
--define:NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER ^
--optimize- ^
--tailcalls- ^
-r: ...many references to framework assemblies and 3rd party assemblies... ^
--target:exe ^
--warn:3 ^
--warnaserror:3239 ^
--fullpaths ^
--flaterrors ^
--highentropyva+ ^
--targetprofile:netcore ^
--nocopyfsharpcore ^
--deterministic+ ^
--simpleresolution ^
file1.fs ^
file2.fs ^
Program.fs
```

I am able to run the above command line, but I do not understand its output and I do not know how to proceed from there: the command creates files named `MyProject.dll` and `MyProject.pdb`. Resulting file is not an `exe`, and is missing its dependencies. I see that VS performs some additional build steps of copying/renaming a file called `apphost.exe` but I do not know why it does so, and how to do it from command line.
My dependencies do not have to be NuGet packages, I can just download the dependencies and place them somewhere in my environment.
I saw the `--standalone` compiler option but as far as I see, it links all dependencies statically, but still outputs `MyProject.dll` and not an executable.

My questions would be then: how do I build an F# project with command line, and get a runnable version of it, with all dependencies resolved and executables linked, everything collected so I can just run it with `MyProject.exe` or `dotnet MyProject.dll`, or some other command? Is there a chance that building "manually" will save me some time compared to just calling `dotnet run MyProject.fsproj`?

Comment: Have you tried `dotnet build`?

Comment: I'd expect `dotnet build` work exactly the same way as `dotnet run` w.r.t. compiling, builting, linking, etc? The only difference would be running (or not) the resulting exe? I'd believe these two incur the same overhead over the build process?

Comment: How about using LINQPad to compile and run? There's Util.Compile and Util.Run in there.

Comment: If your system is so constrained, I would consider using Go instead of .NET, builds are (I would think) likely to be faster.

Comment: The system supports several languages (you can think of it as a kind of an online judge), and Go is already there. With the above question I am trying to address issues related specifically to its F# setup.

Answer (score 1):

> My questions would be then: how do I build an F# project with command line, and get a runnable version of it, with all dependencies resolved and executables linked, everything collected so I can just run it with MyProject.exe or dotnet MyProject.dll, or some other command?

This is what the build system, invoked with `dotnet build`, does. If you try to piece this together manually all you'll end up doing is recreate what it already does for you.

Comment: Probably, yes. But I imagine the `dotnet build` to be a very complex process, which, aside of actual work of compilation, copyig, building, does lots of work to spin up `dotnet` environment, resolve paths, versions, targets, dependencies, settings, which could be not necessary to resolve for me since I know the environment and I can provide the required information as command line options. This is the kind of overhead I'm trying to evaluate. It's possible it will turn out to be insignificant, yes. But it's something I would like to evaluate, if possible, unless its already known to not help.

Comment: This overhead is miniscule in comparison to what you want to do.